# error: unkown type name "my_class"

Tags: c++

So I declared a template class called my_class and I use this class in another file, "main.cpp".

I included "my_class.h" in my main.cpp and I'm getting unknown type name error, anyone know what's going on?

Here is some code:

```
// "my_class.h"
#ifndef TYPE_H_DEFINE
#define TYPE_H_DEFINE

#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

namespace wtvr {

template<class T>
class my_class {
public:
    void add(const T&);
    const T& get();
private:
    std::vector<T> my_class_vec; 
};

template<class T>
void my_class<T>::add(const T& obj) {
    my_class_vec.push_back(obj);
}

template<class T>
const T& my_class<T>::get() {
    std::random_shuffle(my_class_vec.begin(), my_class_vec.end());
    return my_class_vec[0];
}
}

#endif
```

Comment: The code you've shown looks good to me. The problem must lie somewhere in the code you haven't shown.

Comment: You need to post your code. How else do you expect us to figure out what you're doing wrong?

Comment: why is your implementation in your header file?

Comment: Templates cannot be separately compiled so the declaration and definition has to be in one place!

Comment: also in your implementations you have to initialize your templates with a type underneath each implementation of a function

Comment: isnt that what i'm doing??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a tricky one!

Turns out that my include guard names

```
#ifndef TYPE_H_DEFINE
#define TYPE_H_DEFINE
```

was already used by the standard c++ library so I changed it to a different name, no wonder why Bjarne Stroustrup hates macros!! Thank you everybody!

Comment: You could avoid that by using `#pragma once`, although this is no-standard most compilers support it.

Comment: @Torbjörn And it really sucks when they don't. Compilers are allowed to silently discard any `#pragma` they don't support.

Comment: @Torbjörn I know I can  use #pragma once but in practice I would like to use include guards.